# How to get the Operating System's Look & Feel in Java 7?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am coding Java 7 with the Netbeans 7.1 IDE. From the Java 1.7 package they are using a new theme in their applications.

What can I do to make my application's theme exactly the theme in operating system (i.e. if I am using Ubuntu, I want the look and feel of my program to be the that of Ubuntu's)?

Comment: @Justin Nice use of a bounty. I applaud you!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I feel that this is more a question for SO, but in short you should try something like :

```java
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```