# How to change the theme of a Java application in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, themes

I want to change the look of a Java application. I'm just using Netbeans and I don't like the look of metal in it, Instead I want to change it to the Windows look. Is there any way to do it?

I want to make it look like this.

[image]

But instead, when I run it, this is what the default look or theme of it is.

[image]

Is there any steps to change the default look of it?

Comment: Might take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332955/how-to-get-the-operating-systems-look-feel-in-java-7

Comment: Basically, try adding `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` as the very first line of your `public static void main` method. That method controls the look and feel that your swing application runs in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Metal".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(YourJavaApplicationName.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(YourJavaApplicationName.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(YourJavaApplicationName.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(YourJavaApplicationName.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically:

> UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

Will set the Look and feel to the one that your Operating System uses.

Take a look at [this java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) which also lists the available themes and how to apply them.