# Is there any method in java which returns the system's theme color?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am currently working on a `JFrame` which is to be set to fullscreen by the user. When in fullscreen, the title bar has to be removed by the `JFrame`'s `setUndecorated()` method. However doing this deprives the user of the title bar. So I added a `JPanel` named `titleBar` at the top which appears only when the cursor is very close to the `JFrame`'s top. Now the problem is that I want the `titleBar`'s color to be the same as the user has set in his System's settings. I have tried to find a method in the `System` and `Toolkit` classes but it didn't help. Can anyone tell me if there is a method in java that returns me the current System's title bar color. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332955/how-to-get-the-operating-systems-look-feel-in-java-7 ?

Comment: As I mentioned in your other question related to this, you can use `frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME)` so you won’t have to figure out the colors on your own.

Comment: Haven't tried this, but [`SystemColor.activeCaption`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SystemColor.html#activeCaption) looks promising.

Comment: The native PLAF doesn't work for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use UIManager.getColor(key). You have to find the appropriate key for your needs. See this other post for more on the keys:

[Swing UIManager.getColor() keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730649/swing-uimanager-getcolor-keys)